# Adding Access Control Origin to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to allow Access Control Origin due to the following error in an Android Cordova app:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/: Line 0 : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.v2.domain.com/api/v1/users/me/favorites?lat=42.5467&lng=-83.2113&radius=10.0&limit=5&search=' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am trying to figure out where in Kubernetes to add it - I assume it's somewhere in the Service or the Deployment.

Here's both:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: domain-server
  annotations:
    dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: "api.v2.domain.com"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:152660121739:certificate/8efe41c4-9a53-4cf6-b056-5279df82bc5e
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: domain-server
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: domain-server
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: domain-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: domain-server
          image: "152660121739.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/domain-server"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "1200Mi"
            requests:
              memory: "900Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
     ...
```

Is this the correct place to put the header? If so, how would one add CORS to Kubernetes here? I am noticing some suggestions like Nginx ingresses, but the application I am using does not use Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not about Kubernetes. Browsers enforce CORS, check reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS . You can also use **curl** or **postman** and see content without CORS error.

Normally nginx servers can fix that and kubernetes-nginx is not really different. It basically uses reverse proxy to control services. Check this reference to get started to fix CORS error by ingress: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors

Comment: As I stated above, my application does NOT use nginx

Comment: As I stated above it is ingress service with reverse proxy so your service type doesn't matter. It could be java, go, python, js or literally anything else. All ingress service cares is if it has port and directs all requests to that port, check this reference about reverse proxy: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/ . If you have issues in your server you can check how to allow CORS in your service.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much more easier if you use Nginx, that you will have to add just these annotations in service configuration file:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
   more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin";
```

But in your case it seems that problem is connected more with CORS that straight with Kubernetes [cors-article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You have to enable CORS.

You can edit kubernetes API server yaml file, to get CORS working.

Add line **--cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]** argument to **/etc/default/kube-apiserver** or **/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml** file, it depends where your kube-apiserver configuration file is located.

```
spec:
containers:
- command:
  - kube-apiserver
  - --cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]
```

Then restart to kube-apiserver.

Then change annotation `dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: "api.v2.domain.com"` to `dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: "http://api.v2.domain.com"` in your service configuration file and apply changes.