# Nginx ingress with oauth proxy and CORS

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have two services in Kubernetes which are exposed through nginx controller. Service `a` wants to invoke content on domain `b` but at the same time both services need to be authenticated through Google using the oauth-proxy service.

So I have managed to enable CORS and `a` can invoke `b` without any issues. But the problem is when I include the authentication as well, I am constantly getting:

```
Access to manifest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=<obscured>.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fa.example.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=profile+email&state=<obscured>manifest.json' (redirected from 'https://a.example.com/manifest.json') from origin 'https://a.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here are the ingresses:

**Service a**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 0.0.0.0/0
  name: a
spec:
  rules:
  - host: a.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: a-svc
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - a.example.com
    secretName: a-tls

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 0.0.0.0/0
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: a-oauth
spec:
  rules:
  - host: a.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: oauth2-proxy
            port:
              number: 4180
        path: /oauth2
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - a.example.com
    secretName: a-oauth-tls
```

**Service b**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 0.0.0.0/0
  name: b
spec:
  rules:
  - host: b.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: b-svc
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - b.example.com
    secretName: b-tls

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 0.0.0.0/0
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: b-oauth
spec:
  rules:
  - host: b.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: oauth2-proxy
            port:
              number: 4180
        path: /oauth2
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - b.example.com
    secretName: b-oauth-tls
```

Obviously, there is only one difference between these two and that is the cors annotations `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"` in the service b ingresses.

I am not sure of what is causing the issue but I am guessing that the authentication done against Google in service `a` is not being passed to the CORS request so that the service `b` can also be authenticate with the same token/credentials.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: I am using GKE, version: 1.20.9-gke.701.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the whole Kubernetes and Nginx config was correct, so the solution was implementing the usage of the saved cookie on client side when invoking a CORS request to the second service.

Essentially, this was already answered here: [Set cookies for cross origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/7105071)

Excerpt from the answer:

> **Front-end (client)**: Set the XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials flag to
> true, this can be achieved in different ways depending on the
> request-response library used:
>
> - jQuery 1.5.1 xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
> - ES6 fetch() credentials: 'include'
> - axios: withCredentials: true

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, it looks like you lack of annotations for using HTTP.

Try to add fragment like this in  service configuration file:

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
   more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin";
```

But it can be a problem with CORS. In such case you should add the following line:

```yaml
--cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]
```

to  `/etc/default/kube-apiserver`  or  `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`  file (depending on the location your kube-apiserver configuration file).

After that restart kube-apiserver.

See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467736/adding-access-control-origin-to-kubernetes/57467948).

Comment: Hey @WytrzymałyWiktor, I did manage and I was about to put in the answer.